# How can I accessing nested component in react from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I want to access a nested component from parent component.

This is Bill Form.jsx

```
      import BillDetailForm from './BillDetailForm';


         render(){

          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

             <FieldArray

               name= 'detail'
               component={BillDetailForm}
               placeholder= '...detail'
               label='Detail'

                 />
               </form>
                  );
                   }
               }
```

BillForm is the parent component.

This is a nested component or child component of BillForm: BillDetailForm.jsx

```
     render(){


    return(
         <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>


       <div>Detail:</div>
      <FieldArray
        name= 'detail'
        component={RenderDetail}
        label='Detail'
      />

      </form>

    )

}
```

Inside BillDetailForm is RenderDetail:

```
        const RenderDetail = ({fields, meta: { error,submitFailed}},props) => (
          <dl>
         <dt>
            <button type="button" className= 'btn btn-primary' onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add 
        Detail</button>
             {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
           </dt>
               { fields.map((registerDetail, index) =>
               //In the following line renderDetail is accesing Detail component.
               <Detail detailItem={registerDetail} fields={fields} index={index} key={index}/>

               )
             }

            {error && <dt className="error">{error}</dt>}
            </dl> 
            );
```

This is Detail Class Component:

```
          class Detail extends Component{

                   render(){

                   const{detailItem,index,fields,isSubtotal} = this.props;

                        return(


                    <dd key={index}>
                    <br></br>
                    <button className= 'btn btn-light mr-2'
                     type="button"
                     title="Remove detail"
                     onClick={() => { fields.remove(index)
                      if(fields.length == 0 || fields.length === undefined){

                        }
                      try{
                     for(let x in fields){
                     fields.remove(index) 
                     let d = fields.selectedIndex;
                    if(fields.remove(index) && d >= 1 && d< fields.length ){
                    fields.removeAll(index);
                     }
                     }
                  }catch{console.info("deletes non numerical index")}

                      }}> Delete </button>

              <h4>DetailRegister #{index + 1}</h4>

               <Field 
                 id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                 name={`${detailItem}.quantity`}
                 component= {NumberPickerInteger}
                 placeholder= '...quantity'
                 label = "Quantity" 
                  />
          <br></br>
          <h3><b>Product</b></h3>
               <Field 
                id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                name={`${detailItem}.product.code`}
                type="number"
                component= {RenderFieldNumeric}
                placeholder='...Product's code'
               label = "Product's code" 
             />
          <Field 
           id={`${detailItem}._id`}
           name={`${detailItem}.product.name`}
           type="text"
           component= {RenderField}
           placeholder='...Product's name'
           label = "Product's name" 
         />
            <Field 
              id={`${detailItem}._id`}
              name={`${detailItem}.product.price`}
              component= {NumberPickerr}
              placeholder= '...Price'
              label = "Product's price" 
             />
         <br></br>
      <h3><b>Subtotal</b></h3>
       <Field 
          id={`${detailItem}._id`}
          name={`${detailItem}.subtotal`}
          component= {SubtotalWidget}
          placeholder= '...subtotal'
          label = "Subtotal" 
           >
            {isSubtotal}
             </Field>



            </dd>

            );

          }
       }
```

I want to access e.g `${props.detailItem}.subtotal` that is in Detail from BillForm. BillForm accesses to BillDetailForm, BillDetailForm accesses to renderDetail, and last renderDetail acceses to Detail.

The question is: How can I access and use props like quantity and subtotal with dynamic index (props.index) from BillForm? I want to access Detail component from BillForm, respecting the following secuence in order access: BillForm -> BillDetailForm -> RenderDetail -> Detail

Comment: Why not use state management by for that purpose?

Comment: I don't know how to use it. How would it be in code?

Comment: When you are dealing with react don't think in term of HTML, think in term of data that is to be shared all around, now how state will help with this is that it'll be a central point where all your data is, you can access data from there anywher in your components. See Redux.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Comment: You can also use something like React Hooks if you don't wanna go that complex. https://rangle.io/blog/simplifying-controlled-inputs-with-hooks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are saying, it seems you are going against the ethos of React. If your parent component wants access to a piece of data, then that data should start in the parent and be passed down. This way, if the data changes it will call a re-render of components and update all necessary components.

Some other advice. Try not o have so much logic inside your component handlers, it looks messy and will run every render cycle. Abstract this into a method on the class and call it when required.

My example will hopefully help you with your issue, but I recommend having a read of the React documentation as it is very good with simple examples.
The use of class will be deprecated eventually in favour of function components and the Hooks API.

```
class ParentComponent {
  state = {
    value: 0,
  }

  methodToDoSomething = (passedVal) => {
    this.setState({
      value: passVal,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const myState = this.state;
    return (
     <Component {...myState} />
    )
  }
}

class Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    const { value , methodToDoSomething } = this.props;
    return (
     <div onClick={methodToDoSomething}>
      {value}
     </div>
    )
  }
}

// Hooks API

const ParentComponent = () => {
  
  const [stateVal, updateState] = React.useState('myString');

  return (
    <div>
      {stateVal}
      <Component passedVal={stateVal} passedHandler={updateState} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Component = ({ stateVal, passedHandler }) => {
  
  function updateMyValue() {
    passedHandler('menewvalue');
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={updateMyValue}>
     {stateValue}
    <div/>
  )
}
```

To avoid passing lots down all the children components, I would recommend reading up on the Context Hook.

*** UPDATE ***
The above example is rudimentary and tries to answer the question presented, there are always many ways to solve a problem.

Passing props can be messy and a maintenance overhead. Most larger applications will benefit from using a state library to manage their global state. The Context API is a good tool to use to wrap a cohesive set of components so they can share data/props without prop-drilling (passing props down many child components).

Custom hooks are another good way to share data. Create a hook containing your data and any other methods for the task and use this hook inside parent and child components to share said data.

Comment: Bill Form: { // accesing <BillDetailForm detail={detail}/>                                                        
                           detail.map((detail,Index) =>{<renderDetail detail={detail}/>    detail.map((detailItem,index)) =>{<Detail detailItem={detailItem}/>}})}

Comment: But all of your apps variables/data inside a state object in the parent components, and pass them down as props.

Comment: How can I pass in form of props?, I want to access Detail component from BillForm

Comment: @philipjc won't it be better if he uses state management for that purpose? Instead of passing data down layers of hierarchy.

Comment: @FranciscoArias a much better tutorial would be: https://medium.com/@pnpsegonne/tutorial-creating-a-form-with-react-redux-c1b3025cf26b

Comment: @MihirKumar Yes, it would, but I did not want to add too much complexity to my answer to save confusion. It is however something to look into, like Redux. Or even better for smaller apps use the new React Hooks API's

Comment: It will solve the problem?, I'm a bit confused respect to code. But I can understand it. e.g how to access `${props.detailItem}.quantity` that is in Detail Component from Bill Form respect to the post I mention?

Comment: if quantity is apart of the object, detailItem, then it should be a matter of {props.detailItem.quantity}